# Using jQuery, how do I take the widths of <td>s in one table and apply them to the <th>s of another table?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I've got 2 tables. One is acting as the header of the other table (please don't ask why, it really is irrelevant and this will filter through to other answers for me as well). I want to take the width of each cell `<td></td>`within a `<tr>` (div id="tableBody") and apply them to the corresponding `<th></th>` in a different div Table (id="tableHeader")

So my HTML might look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div class="tableHeader">
           <table>
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                       <th>words</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
           </table>
       </div>
       <div class="tableBody">
           <table>
               <tbody>
                   <tr>
                       <td>words and stuff</td>
                       <td>words and stuff and things</td>
                       <td>words and stuff and some other stuff</td>
                       <td>less stuff</td>
                       <td>4</td>
                       <td>stuff and things</td>
                       <td>things and other things</td>
                       <td>stuff</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <!-- bunch of <td>s -->
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <!-- bunch of <td>s -->
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <!-- bunch of <td>s -->
                   </tr>
                   <!-- etc -->
               </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far I've tried a number of different things with jquery that I thought should've worked. I'm only getting the width of the `<td>`s in top the top `<tr>`. Ultimately, I'm assuming an array and possibly a for loop has to be involved.

First, I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $tableBodyCell = $('.tableBody tr:eq(1) td');
    var $headerCell = $('.tableHeader thead tr th');
    var arr = [];
    var thead = [];
    $tableBodyCell.each(function() {
        var $this=$(this);
        var colWidth = $this.width();
        arr.push(colWidth);
        //alert(arr);
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < $headerCell.length; i++) {
        $headerCell.css('width', arr[i]);
    }
});
```

When I would alert `arr[i]`, in the for loop, it would return each independent width per alert, but when I try to apply it to the CSS, it applied the last number of the loop to all of the `<th>s`

So then I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableBodyCell = $('.tableBody tr:eq(1) td').toArray();
    var headerCell = $('.tableHeader thead tr th').toArray();

    for(var i = 0; i < headerCell.length; i++) {
        //alert($headerCell[i].id + " " + arr[i]);
        headerCell[i].css('width', tableBodyCell[i].css('width'));
        //$(this).css('width',arr[i]);
    }
});
```

That didn't work either.
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified code . (Assuming length of tableBodyCell  and headerCell are same) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seF8d/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $tableBodyCell = $('#tableBody tr:first td');
    var $headerCell = $('#tableHeader thead tr th');
    $tableBodyCell.each(function(index){
         $headerCell.eq(index).width($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: errr, no wait. I did something wrong. It did work and it didn't. It seems to apply the width's correctly but they do not match up at all, somehow. I don't get it.

Comment: I modified your code and you are using id as class selector. fixed see jsfidle link

Comment: It must be something with my HTML, because my local version is all over the place. But it does seem to be doing the trick based on the jsfiddle. I'll run with that for now. Much obliged.

Comment: My HTML is a bit misleading it seems too. I put IDs here, where I have classes (same name) in my actual copy. My local HTML is a lot more complicated. I wrote this out to simplify it and I guess I botched it a tad. But you still seemed to hit on the solution. I changed the ids to classes in the HTML above.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theWidth = $("table").eq(0).find("tr > td:first").width();
$("table:gt(0)").find("tr > td:first").width(theWidth + "px");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GpLUX/

Comment: This seems close, but I don't need all of the header cells to be the same width, I need them to match up with the natural width of the body cells as caused by the content within them (Dynamic Tables - I apologize if I didn't mention that. I hope that makes sense. Plus, there may be instances of multiple tables, so I'll need to refer to them by div id, ultimately.